# Optimize using SMTP to send messages

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, email

I have an application that sends emails via SMTP, however it is slower than sin.  Two recipients can take over 20 seconds.  I believe the problem is the program logic.

The program opens a csv with email addresses and display names then using a for loop sends each recipient the message.

The problem is, I fear it is re-establishing SMTP connection every time it sends to the next person in the list.

My question is, how do I setup an SMTP connection and reuse that connection for every user?  (unless that's not why its slow, and someone can tell me why its running so slow)

```
void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get User List
        List<string[]> mycsv = csvRead();

        int total = mycsv.Count;

        // Send Message to each user
        for (int x = 0; x < total; x++)
        {
            //Actual send message
            sendMail(mycsv[x][0], mycsv[x][1]);
        }

    }


private void sendMail(string toEmail, string toName)
    {
        string email = Properties.SMTP.Default.Email;
        string name = Properties.SMTP.Default.DisplayName;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(email, name);

        //Recipient Address
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmail, toName));

        //Formatted mail
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        // htmlMessage and Subject are global
        mail.Body = htmlMessage;
        mail.Subject = htmlSubject;

        SmtpClient smtp = smtpDetails();
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }

private SmtpClient smtpDetails()
    {
        int port = Convert.ToInt32(Properties.SMTP.Default.ServerPort);
        string email = Properties.SMTP.Default.Email;
        string username = Properties.SMTP.Default.Username;
        string password = Properties.SMTP.Default.Password;
        string host = Properties.SMTP.Default.ServerAdd;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Port = port;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
        smtp.Host = host;
        return smtp;

    }
```

VS: 2013 - 4.5 .net - WPF app

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve the speed could be to make a static class for the mail delivery. Eg. a mail handler class with the static method SendMail (where you put your smtpDetails() into.
So there won't be a need to create new instances of the SmtpClient for every call in the loop - just reuse the static method.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a using:

```
 using(SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
 {
      Port = port
      //etc
 }
```

This will dispose of all your smtp connections.